# How to use Jerkson with Enumerations?

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I'm trying to use Jerkson to generate a Json representation of an Enumeration in a method that takes a generic type - but it looks strange. I also tried using case objects instead but the Json result dosent look good either:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}

trait Letter
case object A extends Letter
case object B extends Letter
case object C extends Letter

object Test extends App {
  import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._

  import WeekDay._
  def printWeekDay(weekday: WeekDay) {println("weekday: " + generate(weekday))}
  printWeekDay(Mon)

  def printLetter(letter: Letter) {println("letter: " + generate(letter))}
  printLetter(A)
}
```

When running this I get:

```
weekday: {"$outer":{"ValueSet$module":null},"scala$Enumeration$Val$$i":0}
letter: {}
```

Any ideas on how to get the correct value in Json?

Answer (score 0):

you may need an implicit conversion between your Enumeration and jerkson.Json.JsValue.

playframework use this kind of approach

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Writes

Comment: I can't find anything called jerkson.Json.JsValue. I wrote a converter to com.codahale.jerkson.AST.JValue but it didn't work either :(